# How to stop application if Membership database is not available

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, simplemembership

I am using SimpleMembership with success. But now I would like to add some robustness so that when the database is not available, I can display a web page that alerts users about the problem. However, I am unable to prevent the application from progressing to the login page. How can I do this. The current contents of _AppStart.cshtml are below.

```
@{   
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
{
    try
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("dbContext", "Users", "Id", "Login", autoCreateTables: false);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
      // display error page and prevent display of login page
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The _AppStart.shtml file is only executed once during the lifetime of your web pages application - when it first starts. Failure to access databases after that point won't be caught by _AppStart.cshtml.  Here's a reasonable study on error handling in ASP.NET MVC: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422572/Exception-Handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Thanks. I am reading that page right now. The problem is that even if the database is not available when _AppStart.cshtml executes, the application does not goto global.asax.cs/Application_Error.

Comment: I wouldn't use _AppStart in an MVC app. It was really designed as a simpler replacement for global.asax for Web Pages developers. Use global.asax instead.